# Symfony - Ldap create don't connect to serveur

Tags: php, symfony, ldap

With the PHP function `ldap_connect` it's working:

My controller :

```
/**
* @Route("/ldap", name="ldap")
*/
public function ldap(Request $request) {
    $ldaprdn  = 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com';    
    $ldappass = 'password';  

    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldap://ldap.forumsys.com")
        or die("Impossible de se connecter au serveur LDAP.");

    if ($ldapconn) {

        ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

        // Connexion au serveur LDAP
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
        var_dump($ldapbind); 

        // Vérification de l'authentification
        if ($ldapbind) {
            echo "Connexion LDAP OK ...";
        } else {
            echo "Connexion LDAP KO ...";
        }
    }
}
```

Result : `bool(true)`

But if I use Symfony Ldap it's don't work, did you know why ?

My controller :

```
use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Ldap;

[...]

/**
* @Route("/ldap", name="ldap")
*/
public function ldap(Request $request) {
    $host = 'ldap.forumsys.com';
    $port = 389;
    $version = 3;
    $dn  = 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com';
    $pwd = 'password';
    
    $ldap = Ldap::create('ext_ldap', [ 
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        'version' => $version,
    ]);
    
    $ldap->bind($dn, $pwd);
    var_dump($ldap); 
}
```

Result :

`["connection":"Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Connection":private]=> resource(31) of type (ldap link) ["config":protected]=> array(8) { ["host"]=> string(17) "ldap.forumsys.com" ["version"]=> int(3) ["encryption"]=> string(4) "none" ["port"]=> int(389) ["connection_string"]=> string(28) "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389" ["debug"]=> bool(false) ["referrals"]=> bool(false) ["options"]=> array(3) { ["network_timeout"]=> string(2) "60" ["protocol_version"]=> int(3) ["referrals"]=> bool(false) } } } ["entryManager":"Symfony\Component\Ldap\Adapter\ExtLdap\Adapter":private]=> NULL } }`

I use an [online Ldap](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) test server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually works, it seems like you don't really know how to use it.

Please, read: [The Ldap Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/ldap.html)

While `ldap_bind` returns false when authentication was unsuccessful, Symfony Ldap component's `bind` method returns nothing on success and throws an exception on error (which you can see from the [source code](https://github.com/symfony/ldap/blob/5.4/Adapter/ExtLdap/Connection.php)). In your case, you must check if the connection/authentication was successful with a try/catch block:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Ldap\Exception\ConnectionException;

try {
    $ldap->bind($dn, $pwd);
} catch (ConnectionException $exception) {
    // Error message based on your original code
    echo 'Connexion LDAP KO:' . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: You right, it's the first time I use it. I try to make a `$ldap->query()` and it's work fine. The try/catch works fine too